# How to animate Community Toolkits RadialGauge with MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I would like to animate the radialgauge of the Windows Community Toolkit but unfortunately the UI does not refresh itself after a RaisePropertyChanged.

[image]

Here is my Code:

**View**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RadialGaugeValue}" />
<controls:RadialGauge 
    x:Name="MyRadialGauge"
    Grid.Row="01"
    Value="{Binding RadialGaugeValue}"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="100"
    StepSize="1"
    IsInteractive="False"
    TickSpacing="10"
    TickWidth="0"
    ScaleWidth="4"
    ScalePadding="29"
    ScaleTickWidth="1" 
    MinAngle="245"
    MaxAngle="115"
    Unit="Sparquote"
    NeedleWidth="2"
    NeedleLength="100" 
    MaxHeight="250" 
    Margin="0,20,0,0" 
    NeedleBrush="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightBrush}" 
    FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{x:Null}"
    FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="Green"
    TrailBrush="{ThemeResource SystemColorHotlightBrush}" 
    ValueStringFormat=".&quot;%&quot;">
```

**ViewModel**

```
private async Task DoSavingRateAnimation(double myValue)
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>(value =>
    {
        RadialGaugeValue = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RadialGaugeValue");
    });
    await SavingRateAnimation(progress, myValue);

}

private Task SavingRateAnimation(IProgress<int> progress, double value)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (RadialGaugeValue < value)
        {
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
            i += 1;
            progress.Report(i);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the radialGauge does not update itself.

**Do you have any idea how I could animate the Control?**

Comment: Have you tried use two way bind  `Value="{Binding RadialGaugeValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Thanks man! That's it. But I don't understand why, I thought TwoWay Binding is to change the value in the UI and write it back to the source. And by the way I do not understand why the question was downvoted.

Comment: yes I know, the downvote was shortly after the creation of the question. yes, I tested `Mode="OneWay"` and it does not work. So your answer is right, I need `Value="{Binding RadialGaugeValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set  `RadialGauge` value binding with two way model just like the following.

```
Value="{Binding RadialGaugeValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```